# Center everything in the middle of div, with text on top and on bottom of image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a loading screen with a logo in the middle of the page. I have figured out the JS part but for the life of me, I can not centre the text on top and bottom of the image. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/protonus/gy478pcp/1/) and here is the code, what am I doing wrong. I have tried searching for an answer but all results that I tried never got my div to be centred with the text on top of the logo and on the bottom of the logo.

```js
<-- $(window).load(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".loader").fadeOut(3000).delay(3000);
}); -->
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: white;
}

.loader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}

.centered-loader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader centered-loader">
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <img class="img-responsive pulsate" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/" alt="Logo" />
  <p>This text needs to be below the logo.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [flex direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) is `row`, which means that the items would be positioned horizontally. To position them vertically use `flex-direction: column`:

```js
<-- $(window).load(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".loader").fadeOut(3000).delay(3000);
}); -->
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: white;
}

.loader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}

.centered-loader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader centered-loader">
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <img class="img-responsive pulsate" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/" alt="Logo" />
  <p>This text needs to be below the logo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that @Ori Drori. I have learnt something new and will read up on flex direction.

Comment: @Dino - welcome. Try the [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need your layout to remain `flex-direction: row`, then use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container and give your text elements full width:

```js
<!-- $(window).load(function () {
"use strict";
$(".loader").fadeOut(3000).delay(3000);
}); -->
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: white;
}

.loader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}

.centered-loader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

p {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader centered-loader">
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <img class="img-responsive pulsate" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/" alt="Logo" />
  <p>This text needs to be below the logo.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-align:center and remove display:flex.

```js
<-- $(window).load(function() {
  "use strict";
  $(".loader").fadeOut(3000).delay(3000);
}); -->
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: white;
}

.loader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}

.centered-loader {
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader centered-loader">
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <img class="img-responsive pulsate" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/" alt="Logo" />
  <p>This text needs to be below the logo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't center it vertical though